# How to find the reason for an authorization failure in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using a class derived from `AuthorizeAttribute` for global authorization in my MVC3 application. I use it as a global filter via `filters.Add(new CtsAuthorizeAttribute());`

Now I have implemented a custom role provider and would like to start placing more specific authorization filters on controllers, like this:

```
[CtsAuthorize(Roles = "systemadmin")]
public class CompanyController : CtsController
```

I would like to redirect to a message page (ideally just modify a model property for the failed page) for role based authorization failures, but preserve the default redirect to the login page for login based failures. How, in my override below, can I determnine the reason for the authorization failure?

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
}
```

I can duplicate the 'user in role' check, but it has just been performed by this very filter. I just can't find out how to learn this from the filter.

Comment: What do you consider an "authorization failure"?  Are you grouping authentication failures with this?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs, using the global filter as as, a failure is when the request is not authenticated, and when I apply the filter with `Roles` when the user is not in the specified role.

Comment: A failure in the MS security framework for not differentiating between authentication and authorization, which are very different things.  I would think the short answer is, check if the user is authenticated (this should be available through the context), then check the roles.  Is this the level of granularity you are looking for?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Yes, thanks, in this scenario I can safely assume that if the user is authenticated, they are not authorised. Why no answer with this suggestion? I don't know if this case is an MS failure though. This attribute checks authorization only, to be technical, and in it's base case, only authenticated users are authorized.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  Did I give you the information you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, I suggested putting it in an answer. I typo'd, should be "why NOT answer with this suggestion"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether the user is authenticated through the provided context argument; then the roles can be determined locally.

Comment: Thanks. I don't need to determine roles though, the attribute already does that before calling `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`.